# Facebook "Like" Button Errors

Tags: html, facebook-like

I've added a "Like" button on a page, which points to a different URL. I've also added OG tags to the target page.

However, iit's not working properly. I've run both pages through the Debugger, and both are showing errors.

**Page with "Like" button** (http://www.ilovefish.co/test.html):

*Errors That Must Be Fixed: Can't Download:Could not retrieve data from URL.*

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>

</head>

<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like href="http://www.ilovefish.co/target.html" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

</body>
</html>
```

**Target Page** (http://www.ilovefish.co/target.html):

*Errors That Must Be Fixed:
Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http:// www . ilovefish.co/target.html' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '133031083521499' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.*

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta property="og:title" content="Join The Fish Club" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ilovefish.co/target.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ilovefish.co/images/fish_club.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Fish Club" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="133031083521499" />

</head>

<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Cheers

Mark

Comment: make sure you've entered correct appId and app is not in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Access to internet? I've tried the link you gave. Fortunately, seems like it works for me. You dont need to do anything. Or may be your internet connection is slow

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.ilovefish.co/target.html" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```